# Symfony, allow access to all routes, except one (or two)

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new to Symfony 3. I'm trying to configure the routes that users and admins can access. I have two roles: `ROLE_USER` and `ROLE_ADMIN`, I've configured my `security.xml` as follows:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN


access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

I want to allow the `ROLE_ADMIN` users to access all routes except `login`.
And I want to allow the `ROLE_USER` users to access all routes except `login` and `admin`

I'm not sure why, but it looks like all `ROLE_ADMIN` users also receive the `ROLE_USER`. And I've set the `ROLE_USER` to access all routes (by setting `^/` in its path) which includes the `/admin` and `/login` routes.

The question is: how can I set the path to correctly disallow `ROLE_USER` from accessing the `/admin` and `/login` routes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm not sure why, but it looks like all ROLE_ADMIN users also receive
>   the ROLE_USER

Well, this is the meaning of role hierarchy and you wrote it yourself `ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER`. So, as admin have more privilege than user you can't restrict him to access user ressources.

I don't know why you want this behavior but you can achieve it with a workaround in your controller. Something like :

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
public function loginAction()
{
   $context = $this->container->get('security.context');

   $user = $context->getToken()->getUser();

   $admin = $context->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN');

   if ( $admin ){
       //hey I'm an admin, please redirect me to the correct ressource
   }

   if (  $user  ){ 
       //hey I'm a simple user, what do you want me to do ?
   }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that role hierarchy betrayed me :D 
When I removed it, the roles worked like I need